# Which one is the ring of integers of $K$; $\mathbb Z[\alpha,\frac{\alpha^2}{2}]$ or $\mathbb Z[\alpha,\frac{\alpha+\alpha^2}{2}]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> If $f := T^3 - T^2 + 2T + 8$ and $\alpha$ is the unique real root of $f$, If $K := \mathbb Q(\alpha)$, which one of the following rings are the ring of integers of $K$:
>
> $$\mathbb Z\left[\alpha, \frac{\alpha^2}{2}\right]\quad \text{or}\quad \mathbb Z\left[\alpha,\frac{\alpha + \alpha^2}{2}\right]?$$

If I could compute the discriminant of them, the one with the smaller value would be a larger order, but I know neither computing the discriminant of a ring extended by $2$ elements, nor I can justify that there is no other order with a smaller discriminant.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to compute $(\alpha^2/2)^2$ and see that it isn't in the $\Bbb Z$-module of basis $\langle 1,\alpha,\alpha^2/2 \rangle$, which hints that $\alpha^2/2$ may not be an algebraic integer

$(T^3-T^2+2T+8)(T^3+T^2+2T-8) = T^6+3T^4+20T^2-64$
thus $T^3+3T^2+20T-64$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$,
and then $T^3+\frac 32T^2+5T-8$ is that of $\alpha^2/2$.

Hence $\alpha^2/2$ is not an algebraic integer, so $\Bbb Z[\alpha,\alpha^2/2]$ can't be the ring of integer of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$.

On the other hand, the $\Bbb Z$-module of basis $\langle 1,\alpha,(\alpha+\alpha^2)/2 \rangle$ is stable by multiplication, so it's a subring of the ring of integers.

Comment: How did you compute the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2$, If $f$ is min Polynomial of $\alpha$ then $f(\sqrt{x})f(-\sqrt{x})$ is the min Polynomial of $\alpha^2$, am I wrong? but you did something different, and then how did you conclude ? the coefficients of Min Polynom of $\alpha^2/2$ are not all integers, so it is not algebraic ?

Comment: that's exactly what i did except that i kept the indeterminate $T$ instead of pointlessly putting $\sqrt T$ (whatver that would mean), then replaced $T^2$ with $T$ to go from "a polynomial that vanishes for $T= \alpha$" to get "a polynomial that vanishes for $T = \alpha^2$"